Is there such things as an inversion polynomial?
In enumerative combinatorics there is a descent polynomial that counts the number of permutations in the symmetric group of size n with a descent set equal to some fixed set S.
I was wondering if there was a similar thing for inversions of a permutation. Given some fixed inversion set of two element tuples and some symmetric group of size n, is there a polynomial that counts the permutations that meet these conditions?
